# Trying to identify a short Sci-Fi story - virtual cyber-prison

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I wonder if the StackExchange hive-mind might be able to identify the following short story I read as part of a brilliant anthology in (I think) the late eighties.

The basic premise is that there's a virtual cyber-prison that sedated prisoners experience. The cyber-prison is surrounded by a 'fog' that knocks the prisoners out. No-one has managed to escape.

One prisoner learns to manipulate this virtual reality (so far, so proto-Matrix). At first he just enjoys doing stuff like making a dandelion seed float into the mouth of a yawning guard; but eventually he 'escapes' into the fog, which he also learns to manipulate.

Comment: This should be easy to identify as "late 80s" was the early days of cyberpunk and there weren't that many cyberpunk anthologies from that time. But I'm blowed if I can find it :-( Ed, is there anything more specific you can remember e.g. character names?

Comment: Hi, John. 

Unfortunately not! 

It was a sci-fi anthology rather than specifically cyberpunk - and the 'cyber-prison' may well be my own take on that particular story, rather than the author's. Think the details (as meagre as they are) are fairly accurate. 

I do recall the 'operators' struggling to keep up with the protagonist's actions, due to time in the 'dream world' running at a much faster rate (in a proto-Inception fashion).

Comment: There's a virtual prison story by Barry Longyear, called "The House of If" but the other details don't fit very well.